# jQuery AJAX Long Poll doesn't abort

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, long-polling

I have 2 JS classes:

**First one:**

```
var class1 = function() {
    this.obj = new class2

    this.stopLongPollAjax = function() {
        obj.abort = true;
        obj.ajax.abort();
        delete obj; // it's important part for me
    }
    var self = this;
}
```

**Second one:**

```
var class2 = function() {
    this.abort = false;
    this.ajax = null;

    this.init = function() {
         self.longpoll();
    }

    this.longpoll = function() {
        if(!self.abort) {
            self.ajax = $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: //url here
                complete: function() {
                    self.longpoll();
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    if(response == 1) {
                        // callback
                    }         
            }            
        });
    }
    var self = this;
    this.init();
}
```

When I call `stopLongpoll` method from `class1` `longpoll` doesn't make another loop (when it is completed) but it is not stopping immediately after calling `stopLongpoll` method. Any ideas?

PS: if my code is not easy to read or understand I can explain it.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake was very stupid... In `class1` i forgot to put `self` before operations on `obj`.. It should look like:

```
obj.abort = true;
obj.ajax.abort();
delete obj;
```